# For which values of $a, b$ does the system of equations not have any solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> For which values of $a$ and $b$ does the linear system represented by the augmented matrix *not* have any solution?
>
> $$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
>       1&-2&3&-4\\
>       2&1&1&2\\
>       1&a&2&-b
>      \end{array} \right] $$

---

Truthfully, I don't know where to start. Thus, any help is welcomed. Thank you very much!

EDIT: I tried to solve the problem on my own using Gaussian elimination, but I am not sure that the solution is the right one, or is that the right way to go.

EDIT2: OK, here is how I tried to solve it using Gaussian elimination:
multiplication of the third row with -1, and adding with the first row, the I got
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&3&-4\\
      2&1&1&2\\
      0&2a&-2&2b
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Dividing the third row with 2:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&3&-4\\
      2&1&1&2\\
      0&a&-1&b
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Now my problem is, that I have two variables in one equation. I have no idea how to go next.

Comment: You should add your work to the problem statement so we can help you figure out if it right or, if not, where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes it's a right way or if you know the Cramer's formula then it's the second right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of Gaussian elimination, we arrive at

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & a+1 & -b - 2a\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, when $a = - 1$ and $-b-2a \neq 0 \iff b\neq 2$, there will be no solution to the system of equations. Why not?

Comment: why is b not equal 6. One more question: Can I multiply two rowes? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: A system will be  inconsistent (no solution) if a row is all zero *except* for the rightmost entry, which is nonzero. It represents the "equation" $0x + 0y+0z = c$ where $c\neq 0$. (Hence no solution). If the entire row is zero, then the system has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

By row reduction the system becomes (if I didnt make a mistake (highly likely))

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&-1&2\\
0&0&a+1&-b-2a\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

In order for the rank to be less than $3$ we need that $a+1=0$, so $a=-1$ for no solution we then need $-b-2a \neq 0$ so $b\neq 2$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please explain to me why is the b not equal to 2. How did you get this. Thanks

Comment: the last row must be $0 \ 0\  0 \ x$ where $x$ is non zero since $x=-b-2a$ and $a=-1$ we get $b\neq 2$